# How to insert 100 million entries in FireBase database without painting myself into a corner

Tags: data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning and trying to understand how to optimizing my FireBase database for my use case.

Looking at the code below: Lets say that the `US/STREET_ADDRESS` get pushed 150 million entries(the number of street addresses in the US), and I want to sort on the `"path":` key, since its a unique identifier for all addresses. What would the performance be here when it comes to responce time? If this setup regarding my question is not advicable how can I change the  `US/STREET_ADDRESS`?

Reading about [fan-out](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) but dont think i need that because of no multichat or other multi anything. In my case I simply want to create a databas that holdes the intere worlds all street addresses, for whatever reason :).

Should I denormalize the `US/STREET_ADDRESS` even more, like splitting the 10 million entries into `US/A/STREET_ADDRESS`, `US/B/STREET_ADDRESS` and `US/C/STREET_ADDRESS`. This can be done since the `"path": "US/California/Orange County/3138 E Maple Ave"` in the sample code below is unique, and could even be used as a Key instead of Firebase `postsRef.push()` auto key, that this code sample use. But still there will be 100 millions

```
{
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
  "GB": {
    "name": "United Kingdom"
  },
  "US": {
    "name": "United States",
    "STREET_ADDRESS": {
      "-KUxrqYlItjme2v1I_W5": {
        "id": "hjg86-tg33-8hu4-yh5u",
        "path": "US/California/Orange County/3138 E Maple Ave"
      },
      "-KUJHjj7HG5gGHNNJ_T5": {
        "id": "ds86-tg12-7eu4-juw3",
        "path": "US/Florida/Tampa/104 Biscayne Ave"
      }
    }
  },
  "CH": {
    "name": "Switzerland"
  },
  "SY": {
    "name": "Syrian Arab Republic"
  },
  "TW": {
    "name": "Taiwan"
  },
  "TJ": {
    "name": "Tajikistan"
  },
  "TZ": {
    "name": "Tanzania, United Republic of"
  },
  "TH": {
    "name": "Thailand"
  }
}
```

Comment: Storing data is never the scalability problem. Those come of how you access the data. So make a list of all the ways you want to access the information and see how much data Firebase has to consider for each. That gives you a good indication of the performance you can expect.

Comment: Thanks but is it ok to have one list like this with 150 million rows indexet on the "path". I mean dosent it take time for FireBase to find a particular `path`, is my code a bad construction?

Comment: It depends on the queries you want to do on that list. Querying a record from a list of 150 million records will indeed never perform. Reading a single  record is not a performance problem, it's the query that is.

Comment: Will the query be faster if I make `"US/Florida/Tampa/104 Biscayne Ave" ` the key instead of the `postsRef.push()`? The `path` value is unique only prob is removing forbidden character like [] ,$  #..

Comment: It depends on the query. Discussing data structures without knowing the queries involved is meaningless. Show your query code (in your question, not in comments) and we'll have a place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have query code,,jet still fiddling with it..